# Javascript HighChart having multiple name & data in Series and json object

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I have a JSON object which is retrieved from MySQL using PHP.It is as follows:

```
{
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, null, null]
}
```

The content can vary as it totally depends on data retrieved from database at any point of time.Now in Javascript I 'm plotting HighCharts, and need to use the data retrieved from JSON object, i.e. I' m having series:

```
[{
    name: 'A',
    data: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
    name: 'B',
    data: [4, 5, 6]
}, {
    name: 'C',
    data: [7, , ]
}]
```

Here I have typed array data, but it has to be dynamic, as I'll not be knowing the contents of the array. My expected output is as follows:

```
[{
    name: ' A ',
    data: Array[' A ']
    // should give the data of [1,2,3]
}, {
    name: ' B ',
    data: Array[' B ']
}, {
    name: ' C ',
    data: Array[' C ']
}]
```

Kindly suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Can you post the code which retrieves the data?

Comment: $dataarr="SELECT Data,Year,Type
from tablename
where Type IN(
SELECT DISTINCT(Type)
from tablename)
order by Type, Year";
$resultdata=$mysqli->query($dataarr);

$list=array();
while($row=$resultdata->fetch_assoc())
{
 $list[$row['Type']][]=$row['Data'];

}
$tdata=json_encode($list);
echo $tdata;

Comment: xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
var myobj=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
             doChart(myobj); }

Comment: @csp713 Above are PHP and Javascript code snippets respectively

Comment: So `myobj` is the response with the expected data, and `doChart` creates the chart? What's the problem then, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes myobj has the expected data. But this code below does not work for some reason: series: [ { name: 'A', data: myobj['A'] }] It gives error in the data. The output for myobj['A'] when I display with document.write is 1,2,3. I believe we need to modify series to push the values, but there is not much avilable on the internet about this

Comment: What does the error say? Also, could you post the `doChart` function also?

Comment: function doChart(myo){ document.write(oo(myo['A'])); /* prints 1,2,3 */ Highcharts.chart('container', {

          title: {
             text: 'Test Graph'
           },

          subtitle: {
             text: 'Source: Try'
           },
         
xAxis:
yAxis:                                                                                                       series:
         [{
        name: 'A',
        data:[1,2,3]
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        data:[4,5,6]
    }, {
        name: 'C',
        data:[7, , ]
    },]

}); 
}

Comment: doChart is just a function to get the myObj from xmlhttp request. Above is the function. As you can see, I have manually typed my data values, in the series. But I want to use values form my JSON object myobj/myo.

Comment: I have also tried converting my myo object into arrays as shown below function retriveArray(obj) {
    var vals = [];
    for( var key in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            vals.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return vals;
} and in series data: retrieveArray(myo('A')). But this too doesnt work, as otherwise the function works fine, and gives me an array of that data but when I use it here, it shows error in the data line.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with the object. You should be able to just do `myo.A` or `myo['A']`. The `doChart` function you just posted isn't valid because `xAxis: y:Axis: ` is not correct syntax.

Comment: Yes I removed the title, and axis part as I wasnt allowed to post a long message. But as per my knowledge, its the data which is causing the problem, as rest of the code is works fine when I use data: [1,2,3] etc.

Comment: when I do myo['A'] I dont see the highlighted bar in my graph, in other words, my graph is empty as otherwise when I use [1,2,3] I get to see the plotted lines.

Comment: I threw together a fiddle which should essentially look like what you're trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/wah6xy24/. It shows parsing your object and passing it `doChart`, in which the data arrays pull from `myo`. Without seeing more of the code I can't tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Im new to this, https://jsfiddle.net/Lfsjjm7u/ but here is the complete code. Kindly ignore the commented statements, i was trying many ways to get this done. I guess you know what happens in the backend, a json object is retrived similar to this{
A: [
"1",
"2",], B: [ "3","4"] etc.

Comment: {
10.1: [
null,
null,
"1",
"2",
"3"
],
10.2: [
"4",
"5",
"6" ]}. For this JSON object should i use myo.10.2 to get the values?

Comment: @csp713 hi i have forked a new fiddle with your code, and the above problem.. https://jsfiddle.net/y1wu731z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php to form proper associative array in php.

For current scenario you can update you json data dynamically

```
{
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, null, null]
}
```

to required form

```
[{
  "name": "A",
  "data": [1, 2, 3]
}, {
  "name": "B",
  "data": [4, 5, 6]
}, {
  "name": "C",
  "data": [7, 0, 0]
}]
```

by using code below

```
var dataJ = {
  'A': [1, 2, 3],
  'B': [4, 5, 6],
  'C': [7, null, null]  
}
var highchartsData = []; //series data
Object.keys(dataJ).map((el) => {
  highchartsData.push({
    name: el,
    data: dataJ[el].map(Number) //convert to number
  })
})
```

```js
var dataJ = {
  'A': [1, 2, 3],
  'B': [4, 5, 6],
  'C': [7, null, null]
}
var highchartsData = [];
Object.keys(dataJ).map((el) => {
  highchartsData.push({
    name: el,
    data: dataJ[el].map(Number)
  })
})


Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },


  series: highchartsData,

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your fiddle I think I know what's wrong. Your server response object has the `data` as an array of strings. Apparently highcharts will not automatically parse these strings as numbers, but you can map the array to numbers as such:

```
series: [{
  name: 'A',
  data: myo['A'].map(parseInt)
}, {
  name: 'B',
  data: myo['B'].map(parseInt)
}, {
  name: 'C',
  data: myo['C'].map(parseInt)
}]
```

Comment: oh I shall check it out

Comment: Hi kindly check this fiddle as well I have edited your code: https://jsfiddle.net/y1wu731z/  When I have the JSON obj as {
10.1: ["1","2","3"],
10.2: [
"5",
"5",
"6"
] } myo.10.1 doesnt work?

Comment: Glad it worked. As a note, `myo."10.1"` isn't right. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) out. To use dot notation, "property must be a valid JavaScript identifier". Since `10.2` is not, you must use bracket notation (`myo['10.2']`).

Comment: Hi  parseInt doesnt seem to work for all elements..as I get this : document.write(myo['10.1']+ "\n");// outputs 43934,52503,57177,69658,97031,119931,137133,154175
document.write(myo['10.1'].map(parseInt)); //outputs 43934,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,6,9,617 why does this happen?